# The navigation property 'UId' is not a declared property on type 'Users'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

So i ve tried about everything i found on about all sites but i cant seem to find the correct answer. Could anybody please solve the problem?

here is the class Users:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class Users
{
    [Key,Required]
    public String UId { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public String Psw { get; set; }
    public Boolean Teacher { get; set;}



    public Users(string UId, string Email, string Psw, bool Teacher)
    {
        this.UId = UId;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Psw = Psw;
        this.Teacher = Teacher;
    }

}
```

the class QAnswers which is most likely the problem considering it needs a composite key:

```
[Table("Qanswers")]
public class QAnswers
{

    public int QId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("QId")]
    public Questions Questions { get; set; }

    public int AId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AId")]
    public Answers Answers { get; set; }

    public String UId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UId"), Column(Order =0)]
    public Users Users { get; set; }



    public QAnswers(int qId, int aId, string uId)
    {
        this.QId = qId;
        this.AId = aId;
        this.UId = uId;
    }
}
```

the class Questions:

```
[Table("Questions")]
public class Questions
{
    [Key,Required]
    public int QId{ get; set; }
    public String Question { get; set; }
    public String Method { get; set; }
    public String Teacher { get; set; }



    public Questions(int qId, string question, string method, string teacher)
    {
        this.QId = qId;
        this.Question = question;
        this.Method = method;
        this.Teacher = teacher;
    }
}
```

and the class Answers:

```
[Table("Answers")]
public class Answers
{
    [Key,Required]
    public int AId { get; set; }

    public int QId { get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("QId")]
    public virtual Questions Questions { get; set; }
    public String Answer { get; set; }



    public Answers(int aId, int qId, string answer)
    {
        this.AId = aId;
        this.QId = qId;
        this.Answer = answer;
    }
}
```

Here is the class WebsiteContext:

```
public class WebsiteContext : DbContext
{
    public WebsiteContext() : base("Database1")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Users> Users{ get; set;}
    public DbSet<Questions> Questions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Answers> Answers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QAnswers> QAnswers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<QAnswers>().HasKey(x => new { x.QId, x.AId, 
        x.UId });
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasKey(u => u.UId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasRequired(x => 
        x.UId).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Questions>().HasRequired(x => 
        x.QId).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

And here is the complete exception:

```
The navigation property 'UId' is not a declared property on type 'Users'. 
Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it 
is a valid navigation property.
Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
StackTrace:<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

ok so the problem is this apparently:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Users>().HasRequired(x => 
x.UId).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

however when i comment this i get :

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Qanswers_dbo.Questions_QId' on 
table 'Qanswers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON 
DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY 
constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
StackTrace:<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

So how do i solve that if im not allowed to block cascading?

Comment: The exception is from here `.HasRequired(x => c.UId).WithMany()`. Not sure what are you trying to achieve with that.

Comment: Regarding the edit. The issue is caused by some relationship in `Questions`, `Answers` and/or `QAnswers` classes, you'd better show them in the post.

Comment: added them hope you can solve the problem btw thx for taking your time to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationships are defined by [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx). For your entity model they are:

(1) `Questions` 1 -> 0..N `Answers`

(2) `Questions` 1 -> 0..N `QAnswers`

(3) `Answers` 1 -> 0..N `QAnswers`

(4) `Users` 1 -> 0..N `QAnswers`

all with cascade delete in the direction indicated by `->`.

You can see the *multiple cascade paths* from `Questions` to `QAnswers`:

(A) `Questions` -> `QAnswers`
(B) `Questions` -> `Answers` -> `QAnswers`

The involved relationships are (1), (2), (3), so the cascade delete must be turned off at least for one of them.

The fluent configuration representing each of the relationships is a follows (note the usage of the navigation property where you have it, parameterless overload otherwise):

(1) `modelBuilder.Entity<Answers>().HasRequired(a => a.Questions).WithMany();`

(2) `modelBuilder.Entity<QAnswers>().HasRequired(a => a.Questions).WithMany();`

(3) `modelBuilder.Entity<QAnswers>().HasRequired(a => a.Answers).WithMany();`

(4) `modelBuilder.Entity<QAnswers>().HasRequired(a => a.Users).WithMany();`

To turn the cascade delete off for the desired relationship, just add `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` to it's fluent configuration, for instance

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Answers>().HasRequired(a => a.Questions).WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: thank  you it worked also thx for explaining about the fluent api